# $BE \cap CF = L$. Prove that $K$, $L$ and the circumcenter of $(B, C, E, F)$ are collinear.

Tags: geometry

> $K$ is a point lying on the altitude $AH$ of $\triangle ABC$. $KE \perp CA$ and $KF \perp AB$ $(D \in AB$ and $E \in AC)$. $BE \cap CF = L$. Prove that $K$, $L$ and the circumcenter of $(B, C, E, F)$ are collinear.

[image]

It is evident that $AF \cdot AB = AK \cdot AH = AE \cdot AC \implies (B, C, E, F)$ are concylic.

Let $\overline{E, K, P}$ and $\overline{F, K, Q}$ $(P \in CA$ and $Q \in AB)$ and $O$ being the circumcenter of $(B, C, E, F)$.

It needs to be proven that $\overline{P, O, C}$ and $\overline{Q, O, B}$ for the Pascal theorem for $\overline{E, Q, C}$ and $\overline{F, P, B}$

$\implies \overline{K, L, O}$. Perhaps what needs to be proven is that $E, F, P, Q$ and $P, Q, B, C$ are concyclic.

Comment: Have you proved that $B,C,E,F$ are concyclic?

Comment: We have that $AF \cdot AB = AK \cdot AH = AE \cdot AC$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $EK,FK$ intersect the circumcircle $(B,C,E,F)$ again at $X,Y$, respectively. Then since $\angle XEC,\angle YFB$ are right angles, both $CX$ and $BY$ are diameters of the circle $(B,C,E,F)$; they intersect at the circumcenter $O$. Now invoke Pascal’s theorem for the circle $(B,C,E,F)$ and the six points $E,Y,C,F,X,B$ to conclude that $K,L,O$ are collinear. QED

Comment: That is just in line with what I am currently studying right now - the Pascal theorem. Thanks for that.